# How to get all application link in every page?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.padtube.com/Audio-Files-Player/30-01-1-2.html"
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)

for b in soup.select("table#dl-tbl-list th a[href]"):
    print b['href']
```

When I run this code, it only give me the link only on the first page.
I can't get the application link on next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the site is using `post` to go to next page, so what you need is sending the page number via post.

i did this via http://www.python-requests.org/

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "http://www.padtube.com/Audio-Files-Player/30-01-1-2.html"
#pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)

pageurl = requests.post(url, data = {
    'page': 2
})


pageurl = pageurl.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)

for b in soup.select("table#dl-tbl-list th a[href]"):
    print b['href']
```

Comment: That is a new thing for me. So this mean it only give only application link in page 2 right?

Comment: `requests` is optional, what you need is post page number.

Comment: you can extract it from page elements, `.list-pages` like what you do to extract `href`

Comment: i got this "javascript:prevPage("list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(1, "list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(2, "list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(3, "list-filter-c")
javascript:nextPage("list-filter-c")
javascript:prevPage("list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(1, "list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(2, "list-filter-c")
javascript:goPage(3, "list-filter-c")
javascript:nextPage("list-filter-c")"

Comment: so post param is 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: how to make this code stop or break?
{import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.padtube.com/Audio-Files-Player/30-01-1-2.html"
i = 1
while 1:
    pageurl = requests.post(url, data = {'page': i})
    pageurl = pageurl.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
    has_more = 1
    for b in soup.select("table#dl-tbl-list th a[href]"):
        has_more = 2
        print b['href']
    if has_more:
        i += 1
    else:
        break}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40708/discussion-between-farmer1992-and-wan-mohd-payed)